# awk overwriting files in a loop

Tags: bash, awk, overwrite

I am trying to look through a set of files. There are 4-5 files for each month in a 2 year period with 1000+ stations in them. I am trying to separate them so that I have one file per station_no (station_no = $1).

I thought this was easy and simply went with;

```
awk -F, '{ print > $1".txt" }' *.csv
```

which I've tested with one file and it works fine. However, when I run this it creates the .txt files, but there is nothing in the files.

I've now tried to put it in a loop and see if that works;

```
#!/bin/bash
#program to extract stations from orig files

for file in $(ls *.csv)

do 
    awk -F, '{print > $1".txt" }' $file

done
```

It works as it loops through the files etc, but it keeps overwriting the  when it moves to the next month.

How do I stop it overwriting and just adding to the end of the .txt with that name?

Comment: Just use `>>` to append instead of `>`, which truncates the previous content.

Comment: OMG I knew it would be that simple! Thanks so much! I've spent the last half hour googling why it wouldn't work :D

Comment: it was a typo. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah thanks, I did try to do that, but it said I can "accept an answer in 4 minutes" so will wait and then tick it :)

Comment: `for file in *.csv` would be much better than `for file in $(ls *.csv)`... Parsing the output of `ls` is generally considered rather disfavorably...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are saying `print > file`, which truncates on every new call. Use `>>` instead, so that it appends to the previous content.

Also, there is no need to loop through all the files and then call `awk` for each one. Instead, provide the set of files to `awk` like this:

```
awk -F, '{print >> ($1".txt")}' *.csv
```

Note, however, that we need to talk a little about how `awk` keeps files opened for writing. If you say `awk '{print > "hello.txt"}' file`, awk will keep `hello.txt` file opened until it finishes processing. In your current approach, `awk` stops on every file; however, in my current suggested approach the file is open until the last file is processed. Thus, in this case a single `>` suffices:

```
awk -F, '{print > $1".txt"}' *.csv
```

For the detail on `( file )`, see below comments by Ed Morton, I cannot explain it better than him :)

Comment: You do however need parens `print >> ($1".txt")` for portability and since you've got rid of the loop (right?) you no longer need `>>` you can go back to `>`, i.e. `print > ($1".txt")`. You may also find you need to close open files occasionally if you aren't using gawk.

Comment: @EdMorton so if I understand it properly: in OP's approach the file gets closed when `awk` finishes processing a file (mentally: when arriving to `END`). So in my current approach it is not necessary because all the file pointers are freed at the very end. The only problem would be in case so many files were open at the moment, right?

Comment: @fedorqui correct and gawk internally handles closing files when too many WOULD be open but with other awks you need to do it manually.

Comment: @EdMorton great, always learning from you . Updated, of course feel free to fix any errors!